# How can i make a toast into an Action Listener

Tags: java, android, toast

I'm trying to make a Toast into an ActionListener of a button but it doesn't appear. Kindly, someone can help me?
This is the code of the class.

```
public class Numero extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String server;
    private String porta;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_combinazione);
        server = getIntent().getExtras().getString("server");
        porta = getIntent().getExtras().getString("porta");

        Button btnInvia=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnInvia.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Azioni da fare per inviare combinazione
                        text= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        String num = text.getText().toString();

                        // Mi connetto al server
                        final AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> esegui = new ApriSocket().execute(server, porta, num);
                        if(num < 0) {
                            // Azione
                            Toast.makeText(this,"Numero minore di 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: change this with Numero.this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

`Toast.makeText(this,"Numero minore di 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

to

`Toast.makeText(Numero.this,"Numero minore di 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Numero minore di 0" , 0).show();
```